# vueх как узнать когда закончилась мутация

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Мутации синхронные, и это серьезно мешает мне... Есть ли какие нибудь способы выловить завершение мутации?

Comment: Код, который Вы хотите запустить после мутации, напишите после кода запуска мутации.

Comment: @Дмытрык не будет это работать, тк мутация не успевает закончиться, отсюда и проблема

Comment: тогда, либо через watch наблюдайте за изменением данных, либо  запустите код в `$nextTick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот некоторые варианты:

используя [Vue watch](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: 'pending',
    statusArray: ['success', 'pending', 'info']
  },
  getters: {
    status: state => state.status,
  },
  mutations: {
    updateStatus(state) {
      Vue.set(state, 'status', 'loading');
      setTimeout(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2))
        Vue.set(state, 'status', state.statusArray[index]);
      }, 1000)
    },
  },
})
const {
  mapState
} = Vuex
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'vuewatch',
  store,
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['status'])
  },
  watch: {
    status(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.clear();
      console.log(`Изменено состояние status: ${oldValue} > ${newValue}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1 v-if="status !== 'loading'">{{ status }}</h1>
  <h1 v-else>Loading status</h1>
  <button @click="$store.commit('updateStatus')">change status</button>
  <pre>
    {{ $store.state }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Используя [Vuex watch](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch)

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: 'pending',
    statusArray: ['success', 'pending', 'info']
  },
  getters: {
    status: state => state.status,
  },
  mutations: {
    updateStatus(state) {
      Vue.set(state, 'status', 'loading');
      setTimeout(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2))
        Vue.set(state, 'status', state.statusArray[index]);
      }, 1000)
    },
  },
})
const {
  mapState
} = Vuex
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'vuexwatch',
  store,
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['status'])
  },
  created() {
    this.unwatch = this.$store.watch(
      (state, getters) => getters.status,
      (newValue, oldValue) => {
        console.clear();
        console.log(`Изменено состояние status: ${oldValue} > ${newValue}`);
      },
    );
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.unwatch();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1 v-if="status !== 'loading'">{{ status }}</h1>
  <h1 v-else>Loading status</h1>
  <button @click="$store.commit('updateStatus')">change status</button>
  <pre>
    {{ $store.state }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот метод жизненного цыкла который вызывается после того, как виртуальный DOM был обновлён из-за изменения данных.
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#updated